# python fstring formatting not aligning. Is it the font?

Tags: python, function

Here is my code :

```
txt = f"[{o['idx']:<5}] : {o['k_output']:>8}  {o['r_output']:>8}%
```

But as you can see from the image, they are not aligned from row to row ??

Is it because of font? 
 
[image]

Comment: 43 is two characters 7 is one so you have to fill up with spaces according to the length

Comment: @F.NiX, isn't filling with spaces accordingly the exact point of `{o['idx']:<5}` in the f-string?

Comment: I have  :<5 to fill up the spaces

Comment: code has nothing weird as i see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks ok. Change your font to monospaced.

This code:

```
o = {}
o['idx'] = 43
o['k_output'] = 2.54
o['r_output'] = 0
txt = f"[{o['idx']:<5}] : {o['k_output']:>8}  {o['r_output']:>8}%,"
print(txt)

o = {}
o['idx'] =7
o['k_output'] = 2.54
o['r_output'] = 0
txt = f"[{o['idx']:<5}] : {o['k_output']:>8}  {o['r_output']:>8}%,"
print(txt)
```

Gives that output with monospaced font:

```
[43   ] :     2.54         0%,
[7    ] :     2.54         0%,
```